# Vaadin tree expand issue

Tags: vaadin

I'm using Vaadin tree component to deal with tree menu GUI in web page. I found an issue. I have three hierarchy tree menu. When I expand the second layer tree at first time, it's fine. But if I expand another tree menu which is in same layer with first expanded one, the first expanded one is collapsed. The collapse is not completely. Sometimes it collapse part of tree, sometimes it collapses whole menu that expanded before. Anybody meets this issue?

```
HierarchicalContainer container = new HierarchicalContainer();
container addContainerProperty("caption", String.class, "");
container addContainerProperty("type", String.class, "");
container addContainerProperty("parameter", String.class, "");
Tree tree = new Tree();
tree.setImmediate(true);
tree.setItemCaptionPropertyId("caption");
tree.setContainerDataSource(container);
```

I use nodeExpand method to dynamic add child node when user click root node.

Node Expand method:

```
public void nodeExpand(ExpandEvent event) {
            Item item = getContainer().getItem(event.getItemId());
            getTree().setValue(item);
            String type = String.valueOf(
                    item.getItemProperty("type").getValue()).trim();
            String caption = String.valueOf(
                    item.getItemProperty("caption").getValue()).trim();
            if (type.equalsIgnoreCase("modelSeries")) {
                ModelVariantDataWebservice mvws = new ModelVariantDataWebservice();
                mvws.init();
                ModelVariantDataResponse mvdr = mvws.doWSCall(caption);
                if (mvdr.getModelList() != null
                        && mvdr.getModelList().size() != 0) {
                    String variant;
                    for (ModelVariant mv : mvdr.getModelList()) {
                        variant = mv.getVariant().trim();
                        getContainer().addItem(variant);
                        getContainer().getItem(variant).getItemProperty("type")
                                .setValue("modelVariant");
                        getContainer().getItem(variant)
                                .getItemProperty("caption").setValue(variant);
                        getContainer().setParent(variant, caption);
                    }
                }
            } else if (type.equalsIgnoreCase("modelVariant")) {
                BodyTrimComboDataWebservice btcws = new BodyTrimComboDataWebservice();
                btcws.init();
                BodyTrimComboDataResponse btcdr = btcws.doWSCall(caption.trim()
                        .replaceAll(" ", "%20")
                        + "&series="
                        + String.valueOf(container.getParent(caption))
                                .replaceAll(" ", "%20"));
                    if (btcdr.getModelSeriesVariantlList() != null
                        && btcdr.getModelSeriesVariantlList().size() != 0) {
                    String bodyTrimTitle;
                    String bodyColour;
                    for (BodyTrimComboExtension btc : btcdr
                            .getModelSeriesVariantlList()) {
                        bodyColour = btc.getBodyColour();
                        bodyTrimTitle = "(" + btc.getBodyColour() + " "
                                + btc.getTrimColour() + ") "
                                + btc.getBodyColourDesc() + "-"
                                + btc.getTrimColourDesc();
                        getContainer().addItem(bodyColour);
                        getContainer().getItem(bodyColour)
                                .getItemProperty("type").setValue("bodyTrim");
                        getContainer().getItem(bodyColour)
                                .getItemProperty("caption")
                                .setValue(bodyTrimTitle);
                        getContainer().getItem(bodyColour).getItemProperty("parameter").setValue(caption+";"+btc.getBodyColour()+"-"+btc.getBodyColourDesc()+";"+btc.getTrimColour()+"-"+btc.getTrimColourDesc());
                        getContainer().setParent(bodyColour, caption);
                        getContainer().setChildrenAllowed(bodyColour, false);
                    }
                }
            }

        }
```

Comment: it might help to provide the vaadin version and some example code, where one could try it out...

Comment: I'm using vaadin 7.3.4.

Comment: Sorry, I'm new user to stackoverflow.

Comment: Problem might be in your nodeExpand method, so you should show some code.

Comment: A few comments on the code, probably does not solve your problems but might still help. You are referring to parentId with the variable caption in setParent(childId, parentId). This might work but it might cause some problems when you do all kind of trims and whatnot. better use the event.getItemId() that you already have handy. Also, addItem returns an item object which you could use instead of having to call getContainer().getItem(variant) all the time